# Why is water leaking out of wall-side of tub diverter?

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures, diverter

I have a tub spout with diverter, the type you pull up on a knob/rod at the outflow end of the faucet to turn on the shower. The gate/pull-rod assembly was recently sticky so I uninstalled the spout to soak and clean it. It is a press-on type faucet with a set screw near the wall.

After reinstalling it, it now leaks water out the back, the wall-side -- out the hole where the set screw sits -- when the faucet is on and the diverter is open, i.e. when the tub is filling. (It's as though water is making it out of the supply, down the length of the faucet, then leaking back in the faucet housing and draining out where the set screw is). It does not look like this is the case when the shower is in use.

It seems like water could get back into the wall via this route, so I'd like to address it. Why is this happening (reinstalled incorrectly?), and how do I stop it?
[image]

Comment: do you have another bathroom with the same spout?

Comment: What did you soak it in?

Comment: possibly a damaged seal of some sort.  got photos?

Comment: I do not have another one @jstola.

Comment: @JACK I soaked it in a mix of vinegar, baking soda and hot water.

Comment: @Jasen I don't have pics but could post some. Is it useful to see the leak with the faucet in place?

Comment: Some slide on spigots have an O ring and if not carefully installed the oring is cut and allows water to leak and drain out the back the same as you have happening.

Comment: @Jasen I added a photo if that's helpful

Comment: I vote with Ed, O ring damaged or compromised.

Comment: got photos of the connecting parts?